# Mixpanel data getting wrong from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, analytics, mixpanel

I am working on to show analytics of user visits on a page and unique user visits on a page using mixpanel. We are storing events in mixpanel there is an event named Page Visit from where using currentUrl I am getting the data for the page visits. when I check the data in mixpanel and from the api, I am getting correct page visits but the data for unique page visits is comming out +20-40 , I am using type=unique in the api while making the call I am getting the csv format data and getting the data using the following code in react

```
const helper = await res.text();
const lines = helper.split(/\r?\n/);
const helper2 = await resnotunique.text();
const lines2 = helper2.split(/\r?\n/);
var csvData2 = [];

var csvData = [];
for (let i = 1; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
  csvData[i - 1] = lines[i].split(",");
  csvData2[i - 1] = lines2[i].split(",");
}

for (let i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
  value = +value + +parseInt(csvData[i][1]);
  value2 = +value2 + +parseInt(csvData2[i][1]);
}
```

Here res is the result of the total page visits api call and renotunique is the api result of the unique page visits.

I have checked my api calls and tried in postman but the data is adding up to be wrong only for the unique page visits.
I am expecting correct data from mixpanel. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
Just put interval query in the api and specify the no of days in query to get a combined data for the days which is infact correct